# I want to edit the fourth variable of my class, but I seem to edit them all

Tags: java, class, oop

What my program does now:

- I create a person object with the following information: `firstname`, `lastname`, `birthdate` (the data is different class).
- The date class, has four variables: day, month, year and 18+ (yes or no).

What does work: I can create a person object with a `firstname`, `lastname` and `birthdate` succesfully.

My person class (what looks like it works).

```
public class Person {

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public Date date; 

    public String toString() {
        return (firstName + " " + lastName + " (" + date); 
    }


    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, Date date) {
        this.firstName = firstName; 
        this.lastName = lastName; 
        this.date = date; 
    }
```

}

MY class including my main, where I also have a method where I create my person(s).

```
public static Person setName() {

    String name; 
    String lastName
    String inputBirthdate;
    Date niceDate 
    Date newDate; 


    System.out.println("Firstname:");
    firstName = userInput();  
    System.out.println("Lastname:");
    lastName = userInput(); 
    System.out.println("Birthday:");
    inputBirthdate = userInput(); 
    niceDate = new Date(inputBirthdate);
    newDate = new Date(niceDate);

    return new Gast(firstName, lastName, newDate); 

}
```

And then I have my Date class, where I check if the input of the date is correct. Please not that I can get my Date class to work correctly WITHOUT the 4th variable.

```
public class Date {

public String day; 
public String month; 
public String year;
public boolean child; 

public String toString() {
    return (day + "." + month + "." + year + "." + child);
}


/*Date(String day, String month, String year, boolean child) {
    this.day = dag; 
    this.month = month; 
    this.year = year; 
    this.child = child; 
}*/ //don't need this one, output is the same

public Date(Datum niceDate) {
    int bYear = Integer.parseInt(niceDate.year;
    int bMonth = Integer.parseInt(niceDate.day);
    int bDay = Integer.parseInt(niceDate.day);

    boolean child = false; 

    if (bYear > 1995) {
        this.child= true; 
    } else if (bYear == 1995 && bMonth > 10) {
        this.child = true; 
    } else if (bYear == 1995 && bMonth == 10 && bDay > 1) {
        this.child = true; 
    } else {
        this.child = false; 
    }  

}

public Date(String birthdate) {
    String patroon = "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}";
    boolean b = birthdate.matches(patroon);
    if (b) {
        String[] str = birthdate.split("-"); 
        for (String s: str)
        this.day = str[0];
        this.month = str[1];
        this.year = str[2];
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Birthday is formatted wrong");
    } 
}
```

}

If I run this (witch the check of adult or not (the check looks like it work!), However, my input of the `birthdate` returns null:

```
   Room 1: Name name (null.null.null)false    //boolean works, date not
   Room 2: available
```

I think the problem is that in my second method in my `Date` class, the `public Date(Date Nicedate)` deletes my date after parsing it to an int.

So basically I only want to return the Boolean and keep my Strings exactly the same, and only editing them for using them as an Int for the calculations.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Probably it's a very simple solution, but I've been working on it all day and don't see the solution.

EDIT AS REQUESTED: (I've the this statements in the public Date(datum niceDate) but the date still won't show. Hmmmmm:

```
public Date(Datum niceDate) {
        this.year = year; 
        this.day = day; 
        this.month = month; 

    int bYear = Integer.parseInt(niceDate.year;
    int bMonth = Integer.parseInt(niceDate.day);
    int bDay = Integer.parseInt(niceDate.day);

    boolean child = false; 

    if (bYear > 1995) {
        this.child= true; 
    } else if (bYear == 1995 && bMonth > 10) {
        this.child = true; 
    } else if (bYear == 1995 && bMonth == 10 && bDay > 1) {
        this.child = true; 
    } else {
        this.child = false; 
    }  

}

public Date(String birthdate) {
    String patroon = "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}";
    boolean b = birthdate.matches(patroon);
    if (b) {
        String[] str = birthdate.split("-"); 
        for (String s: str)
        this.day = str[0];
        this.month = str[1];
        this.year = str[2];
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Birthday is formatted wrong");
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share your `main` method?

Comment: `public Date(Datum niceDate)` never sets the `day`, `month`, or `year` fields in your `Date` class.

Comment: >boolean child = false; 
it's unused

Comment: if (bYear > 1995) {
        this.child= true; 
    } else if (bYear == 1995 && bMonth > 10) {
        this.child = true; 
    } else if (bYear == 1995 && bMonth == 10 && bDay > 1) {
        this.child = true; 
    } else {
        this.child = false; 
    }  
This can be simplified to just 1 statement.

Comment: @Code-Guru I've tried that, but somehow that doesn't work either.

Comment: @swennemen Please show exactly what you have tried so that we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you create `newDate` from `niceDate`, you are not copying the day/month/year.

If you look in your `public Date(Datum niceDate)` constructor, the only instance variable that you set is `this.child`, but you also need to set `this.day`, `this.month`, and `this.year`.

Also, I recommend you instead create a function for the date calculation called `isAdult` as a method of your `Date` class, and just call `niceDate.isAdult()` if you need to show whether the date is 18+ years ago. Otherwise, it's easy to make a mistake and have `this.child` be incorrect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply. 

I've toyed arround with adding this.month = month, this.day = day, this.year = year; in my public Date(Date niceDate) however, It will still output null null null. 

I will look into your recommondation, and see if I can figure it out. 

THanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Date(Datum niceDate) {
    this.year = year;
```

In this constructor, `this.year` and `year` refer to the same member variable. So you are assigning the value of that variable to itself.

Then later you do

```
int bYear = Integer.parseInt(niceDate.year);
```

which parses the value from `niceDate` and assigns its value to a **local** variable named `bYear`. Instead, you need to assign the result of `parseInt` to `this.year`:

```
this.year = Integer.parseInt(niceDate.year);
```

You can make similar changes to all of the other variables.